# How to use @Media queries

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm creating an email template and I am trying to make it responsive now I've run into a problem, I have been looking into using the `"@media"` tags but emails don't really like `<style>` so I'm really not sure how to do it.

```
<body>
 <table>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     text blah blah
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<!-- This is the one I was responsive (The one below) -->
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Make this table responsive <3
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </table>
</body>
```

P.S, I don't need the top  to be responsive so how can I link the second one to the CSS

I have all my tables and the Desktop design look perfecto' E.G the divs and tables are '%' not 'px' and I have 2 divs next to each other when it get scaled down to mobile they are still at 50% of the browser screen (50% of the mobile and desktop) but when they get scaled down I want them to be 100% of the mobile screen

Comment: in the <head>, inside <style>

Comment: I can't Gmail and Outlook ignore <style>  ,thats my problem

Comment: Try Ink (http://zurb.com/ink/). It's a responsive email framework made by the group behind Foundation. At least for a reference on how they're structuring tables and the media queries they use (600pxbreakpoint).

Comment: They don't ignore it, just add !important

Comment: Outlook does not ignore style and Gmail web client (not mobile app) can accept some elemental stylings. Stylesheets are not taboo anymore in email, but definitely should only be used to add onto an existing inline built email, and not as part of the foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 771px) {
            /*add your class and code here*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: I can't Gmail and Outlook ignores <style> ,thats my problem

Comment: I'm doing this all day long, they don't ignore <style> Add !important

Answer (score 0):

`<style>` tag would go into the `<head>` tag.

But be careful what you use some platform have [abysmal](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) [email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) [CSS support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), also see [this](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/).

I would limit my use of CSS3/HTML5 in emails.

But honestly I wouldn't bother with building it from scratch, it's just too tedious of a task; you have to get it working on different platforms.

I would use an email HTML builder (most are free) like:

- [stamplia](https://builder.stamplia.com)
- [campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/email-templates/)
- [litmus](https://litmus.com/email-builder)
- [inkbrush](https://www.inkbrush.com)

*Note: Conventionally with HTML emails you would lay everything out with tables, not grids.

Comment: Well the thing is im practically done halve of it is resonsive just with the csss inline I have put in

Comment: You can keep going with it, just put the style in head, and remember that emails use tables for layout, not the grid system due to different CSS support.
It could get difficult of you to maintain by code as it grows, I would still use a builder, it should be simple to port things over to a GUI

Comment: Like I said I have nearly finshed whith the table/email inthe format its jst making it a little more resonsive

Answer (score 0):

In HTML emails, you have two ways to do all of your styling, since you can't have a seperate stylesheet.

The first is a `<style>` tag.
Your email will have a structure of `<html>`->`<head>`->`<body>`.

`<style>` tags can only be placed in the head so your set up should look something like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @media screen only (max-width:767px){
        /* Your CSS goes here */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    /*HTML Code goes here */
  </body>
</html>
```

The other option you have will only work if you just want to change width, and that would be using percents in your element's inline styling, like this:

```
<div class="header-block" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

You can find more on using media queries in emails on [litmus.com](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email).

If you already have it made up with extra CSS in your style tag, the [Inline styler](https://inlinestyler.torchbox.com/) tool might be able to help you convert embedded styles to inline.

Comment: I would do this however when veiwed in GMIAL or Outlook it ignores any <style> elements

Comment: Except, it doesn't open up an email and paste this in through the inspect element, it will yield a red h1 tag.
`<style>
    h1{
    color:red !important;
    }
  </style>


  <h1>hello</h1>`

You just need `!important` because Google's email client will have priority, unless you use `!important`.

Comment: Allow me 5 mins to try :)

Comment: Am I allowed to do this?        <style> 
      table[class="mobile_version"{ 
        color:red !important; 
      } </style>

Comment: You should be able to, why wouldn't you just use `.mobile_version` instead of all of the `table[]` ?

Comment: Not working `      <style> 
      @media screen and (max-width:300px)
      .mobile_version{ 
        background-color:red !important; 
      } 
      </style> `

Comment: When it goes under 300px I want to to change

Comment: How are you inputting the HTML? it's working for me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to using media queries - mobile first or desktop first.

The way that has the most support and is likely the easiest for someone just entering into HTML CSS is desktop first approach. In this you will inline all the styles for your desktop rendering.  You then add media queries for the different breakpoints to make the email fit the device screen.  This is easiest and has most support as the only mobile email clients that do not really support media queries are ones like the Gmail App (which are usually a small percentage of your mobile audience).  The issue is that, using the Gmail App as an example, depending on how you styled your email, this may cause it to break on Gmail app - causing display issues.

This is where the mobile first approach comes in. Mobile first builds the email with inline styles to display correctly in gmail app and then uses media queries and mso conditional statements to make it flesh out and fill correctly on a desktop display.  This requires much more knowledge of CSS and email client 'quirks and hacks' but can create emails that display beautifully across all clients. This can sometimes require much more styling and much more code to accomplish due to the complexity of the different processors in email clients.

For initial forays I would recommend building as always desktop first and then use media queries for mobile as it is simple and is much more widely supported, so requires much less hacks.

For help with supported CSS, please reference - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

Hope this info helped.

References:

Litmus - https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email

Email on Acid - https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/media_queries_in_html_emails

CampaignMonitor - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3163/optimizing-your-emails-for-mobile-devices-with-media/

Comment: Hiya great answer BTW. I have all my tables and the Desktop design look perfecto' E.G the divs and tables are '%' not 'px' and I have 2 divs next to each other when it get scaled down to mobile they are still at 50% of the browser screen (50% of the mobile and desktop) but when they get scaled down I want them to be 100% of the mobile screen

Comment: This may be best accomplished by setting them inline to 100% width and set a max-width in px to a little less then half.  You should also add float(for div or align for tables- table is much more universally supported) and display:block or inline-block. Then to support Outlook and other such, maybe put an MSO conditional table around them with defined widths and add a class to your DIVs that defines a width in desktop style sheet and then add media queries to push back to 100% after certain size. I would recommend using tables instead of DIVs, due to structure support though.

Comment: This may be a good reference for you in your search: http://julie.io/writing/responsive-layout-email-ux-munich-newsletter/

Answer (score -1):

already done and use and try it
Its not using in Media inside a table structure

```
<table width="600px" max-width="100%" align="center">
  <tr><td>content......</td><td>content....</td></tr>
  <tr><td>content......</td><td>content....</td></tr>
  <tr><td>content......</td><td>content....</td></tr>
  <tr><td>content......</td><td>content....</td></tr>
</table>
```